# Selected text in browser converted to a contact in Google Contacts

Tags: google-contacts, google-chrome-extensions, bookmarklet

In email messages and sometimes on web sites, there will be a block of information I'd like to add as a contact in my Google Contacts list. Is there a Google Labs experiment, Chrome extension, Firefox add-in, bookmarklet, or any other tool which allows me to do this more easily? Ideally, given a block of selected text, it should figure out name, postal address, phone number, email addresses, web sites, and then put each in its proper place in a new Google Contacts entry.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Chrome Extension: [Chrome Contact Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-contact-manager/digcngkkccgnojkgolblchebmcjiafdi/related).

> The extension is designed to parse selected text on a website for contact data and store that contact data to your Google contacts.
>   Usage:
>
> Select text on a website and then click the extension button. Selected text parts will be shown and the user is able to drag and drop the correct data into the according fields. Already found data will be placed immediately into the correct fields

Comment: Are you affiliated with this? If so, you need to disclose it in your answer. Also, this has not gotten any good reviews and seems to require that you put your Google credentials in as plaintext. I wouldn't use it.